# Unable to navigate to index.html at project root level from spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

In my project I am using spring boot. For some reason, I need to keep my index.html directly under project folder.

When I return "/index.html" from my rest controller, spring boot is not able to find the index.html. If I move index.html to **src/main/webapp**, index.html is displayed correctly.

Is there any way I can make spring boot load index.html which is directly under project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with main page of swagger and achieved it in this way(adopting the code for your needs):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index.html")
public class SwaggerController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String mainUi() {
        return "redirect:/index.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not helping  :(

I added something like 

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/reports")
public class ReportController {
 
 @RequestMapping("/demo")
 public String demo() {
   return "redirect:/index.html";
 }
}